# What is the best way to do automatic attribute assignment in Python, and is it a good idea?

Tags: python, attributes, decorator

Instead of writing code like this every time I define a class:

```
class Foo(object): 
     def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.e = e
        self.f = f
        self.g = g
```

I could use [this recipe for automatic attribute assignment](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/551763/).

```
class Foo(object):
     @autoassign
     def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
        pass
```

**Two questions**:

1. Are there drawbacks or pitfalls associated with this shortcut?
2. Is there a better way to achieve similar convenience?

Comment: +1 this is a recurrent pattern in Python. I don't see any drawback in using the autoassign decorator, as it lets you define a list of argument *not* to assign.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389180/python-automatically-initialize-instance-variables

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are some things about the autoassign code that bug me (mostly stylistic, but one more serious problem):

1. `autoassign` does not assign an
   'args' attribute:

   ```
   class Foo(object):
       @autoassign
       def __init__(self,a,b,c=False,*args):
           pass
   a=Foo('IBM','/tmp',True, 100, 101)
   print(a.args)
   # AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'args'
   ```
2. `autoassign` acts like a decorator.
   But `autoassign(*argnames)` calls a
   function which returns a decorator.
   To achieve this magic, `autoassign`
   needs to test the type of its first
   argument. If given a choice, I
   prefer functions not test
   the type of its arguments.
3. There seems to be a considerable
   amount of code devoted to setting up
   `sieve`, lambdas within lambdas,
   ifilters, and lots of conditions.

   ```
   if kwargs:
       exclude, f = set(kwargs['exclude']), None
       sieve = lambda l:itertools.ifilter(lambda nv: nv[0] not in exclude, l)
   elif len(names) == 1 and inspect.isfunction(names[0]):
       f = names[0]
       sieve = lambda l:l
   else:
       names, f = set(names), None
       sieve = lambda l: itertools.ifilter(lambda nv: nv[0] in names, l)
   ```

   I think there might be a simpler way. (See
   below).
4. `for _ in
   itertools.starmap(assigned.setdefault,
   defaults): pass`. I don't think
   `map` or `starmap` was meant to call
   functions, whose only purpose is their
   side effects. It could have been
   written more clearly with the mundane:

   ```
   for key,value in defaults.iteritems():
       assigned.setdefault(key,value)
   ```

Here is an alternative simpler implementation which has the same functionality as autoassign (e.g. can do includes and excludes), and which addresses the above points:

```
import inspect
import functools

def autoargs(*include, **kwargs):
    def _autoargs(func):
        attrs, varargs, varkw, defaults = inspect.getargspec(func)

        def sieve(attr):
            if kwargs and attr in kwargs['exclude']:
                return False
            if not include or attr in include:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # handle default values
            if defaults:
                for attr, val in zip(reversed(attrs), reversed(defaults)):
                    if sieve(attr):
                        setattr(self, attr, val)
            # handle positional arguments
            positional_attrs = attrs[1:]
            for attr, val in zip(positional_attrs, args):
                if sieve(attr):
                    setattr(self, attr, val)
            # handle varargs
            if varargs:
                remaining_args = args[len(positional_attrs):]
                if sieve(varargs):
                    setattr(self, varargs, remaining_args)
            # handle varkw
            if kwargs:
                for attr, val in kwargs.items():
                    if sieve(attr):
                        setattr(self, attr, val)
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return _autoargs
```

And here is the unit test I used to check its behavior:

```
import sys
import unittest
import utils_method as um

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_autoargs(self):
        class A(object):
            @um.autoargs()
            def __init__(self,foo,path,debug=False):
                pass
        a=A('rhubarb','pie',debug=True)
        self.assertTrue(a.foo=='rhubarb')
        self.assertTrue(a.path=='pie')
        self.assertTrue(a.debug==True)

        class B(object):
            @um.autoargs()
            def __init__(self,foo,path,debug=False,*args):
                pass
        a=B('rhubarb','pie',True, 100, 101)
        self.assertTrue(a.foo=='rhubarb')
        self.assertTrue(a.path=='pie')
        self.assertTrue(a.debug==True)
        self.assertTrue(a.args==(100,101))        

        class C(object):
            @um.autoargs()
            def __init__(self,foo,path,debug=False,*args,**kw):
                pass
        a=C('rhubarb','pie',True, 100, 101,verbose=True)
        self.assertTrue(a.foo=='rhubarb')
        self.assertTrue(a.path=='pie')
        self.assertTrue(a.debug==True)
        self.assertTrue(a.verbose==True)        
        self.assertTrue(a.args==(100,101))        

    def test_autoargs_names(self):
        class C(object):
            @um.autoargs('bar','baz','verbose')
            def __init__(self,foo,bar,baz,verbose=False):
                pass
        a=C('rhubarb','pie',1)
        self.assertTrue(a.bar=='pie')
        self.assertTrue(a.baz==1)
        self.assertTrue(a.verbose==False)
        self.assertRaises(AttributeError,getattr,a,'foo')

    def test_autoargs_exclude(self):
        class C(object):
            @um.autoargs(exclude=('bar','baz','verbose'))
            def __init__(self,foo,bar,baz,verbose=False):
                pass
        a=C('rhubarb','pie',1)
        self.assertTrue(a.foo=='rhubarb')
        self.assertRaises(AttributeError,getattr,a,'bar')

    def test_defaults_none(self):
        class A(object):
            @um.autoargs()
            def __init__(self,foo,path,debug):
                pass
        a=A('rhubarb','pie',debug=True)
        self.assertTrue(a.foo=='rhubarb')
        self.assertTrue(a.path=='pie')
        self.assertTrue(a.debug==True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(argv = sys.argv + ['--verbose'])
```

PS. Using `autoassign` or `autoargs` is compatible with IPython code completion.

Comment: I also found your autoargs incredibly handy. One issue I noticed is that it seems to throw an error if `defaults` is `None`, because the call to `reversed` fails. Am I right in thinking that this should be fixable by adding an `if defaults:` in front of the line `for attr,val in zip(reversed(attrs),reversed(defaults)):`, or does that have unintended sideeffects? The unit test passes.

Comment: @m01: Sorry for the very belated response. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @unutbu Just a nit but in 3.10.x `inspect.getargspec(func)` **getargspec** is deprecated. you should use `inspect.getfullargspec(func)` instead

Answer (score 21):

From **Python 3.7+** you can use a [Data Class](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/), which achieves what you want and more.

It allows you to define *fields* for your class, which are attributes automatically assigned.

It would look something like that:

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: str
    b: int
    c: str
    ...
```

The `__init__` method will be automatically created in your class, and it will assign the arguments of instance creation to those attributes (and validate the arguments).

Note that here **type hinting is required**, that is why I have used `int` and `str` in the example. If you don't know the type of your field, you can use [Any from the `typing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any).

Comment: Backport for **Python 3.6**: The [PEP 557](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/) references a [sample implementation](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses) ([permalink as of 2019-10-28](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/tree/abf5b5461a23ab8eeda7eaf5e30942ddb986da88)) on GitHub which has a [pypi/pip module](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/) as well. Therefore it can be installed by `pip install dataclasses`.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there a better way to achieve similar convenience?

I don't know if it is necessarily better, but you could do this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


>>> foo = Foo(a = 1, b = 'bar', c = [1, 2])
>>> foo.a
1
>>> foo.b
'bar'
>>> foo.c
[1, 2]
>>>
```

Courtesy Peter Norvig's [Python: Infrequently Answered Questions](http://norvig.com/python-iaq.html).

Comment: This is a quick solution to the problem, but it has two drawbacks: 1) you have to add much more code if you want to make sure that some arguments are passed to the function; 2) the signature of the function is completely opaque, and it cannot be used to understand how to call the function; one will need to rely on the docstring instead

Answer (score 6):

One drawback: many IDEs parse `__init__.py` to discover an object's attributes. If you want automatic code completion in your IDE to be more functional, then you may be better off spelling it out the old-fashioned way.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of variables, you could pass one single configuration dict or object.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the above, though not the same... the following is very short, deals with `args` and `kwargs`:

```
def autoassign(lcls):
    for key in lcls.keys():
        if key!="self":
            lcls["self"].__dict__[key]=lcls[key]
```

Use like this:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, *args, **kwargs):
        autoassign(locals())
```

Answer (score 2):

This a simple implementation by [judy2k](https://codegists.com/snippet/python/auto_argspy_judy2k_python):

```
from inspect import signature

def auto_args(f):
    sig = signature(f)  # Get a signature object for the target:
    def replacement(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Parse the provided arguments using the target's signature:
        bound_args = sig.bind(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # Save away the arguments on `self`:
        for k, v in bound_args.arguments.items():
            if k != 'self':
                setattr(self, k, v)
        # Call the actual constructor for anything else:
        f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return replacement


class MyClass:
    @auto_args
    def __init__(self, a, b, c=None):
        pass

m = MyClass('A', 'B', 'C')
print(m.__dict__)
# {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C'}
```

Answer (score 2):

In [this package](https://github.com/smarie/python-classtools-autocode) you can now find

- `@autoargs` inspired by [answer-3653049](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653049/7262247)
- `@autoprops` to transform the fields generated by `@autoargs` into [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#property), for use in combination with a validation library such as [enforce](https://github.com/RussBaz/enforce) or [pycontracts](https://andreacensi.github.io/contracts/).

Note that this has been validated for python 3.5+

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

You just can't use *args, but you can store in some instance list (like self.args, don't know)