# PyCharm template for python class __init__ function

Tags: python, class, attributes, pycharm

I have a python class with several init variables:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, d1, d2):
        self.d1 = d1
        self.d2 = d2
```

Is there a way to create this code automatically in PyCharm, so I don't have to type explicitly:

```
self.dn = dn
```

This pattern happens very often in my code. Is there a better (Pythonic) way to initialize classes?

I have already seen this post ( [What is the best way to do automatic attribute assignment in Python, and is it a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652851/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-automatic-attribute-assignment-in-python-and-is-it-a)), but I don't want to use a decorator as it makes the code less readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start by making a custom [Live Template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/live-templates.html). I'm not sure about whether you can auto-generate variable number of arguments this way, but, for two constructor arguments the live template may look like:

```
class $class_name$:
    def __init__(self, $arg1$, $arg2$):
        self.$arg1$ = $arg1$
        self.$arg2$ = $arg2$
$END$
```

This is how I've set it up in PyCharm:

[image]

---

Or, you can change the way you set the instance attributes and generalize it for N arguments, see:

- [How can you set class attributes from variable arguments (kwargs) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187082/how-can-you-set-class-attributes-from-variable-arguments-kwargs-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

I learned of another way to solve this.

- Move cursor to argument
- Press alt + enter
- Select Add field '[arg]' to class for single arg -or-
- Press right arrow key to open sub menu
- Select Fix all 'unused local' problems to add all args

[image]

Comment: Very handy thank you. In version 2020.2 the "Fix all" option is gone. Anyone knows how to add it back?

Comment: It looks like they may have removed it.  Not sure why.  I hope this isn't intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Partially answering my own question:

> Very handy thank you. In version 2020.2 the "Fix all" option is gone.
> Anyone knows how to add it back?

I haven't found a way to add the missing option back, but a workaround that will accomplish the same, adding all missing fields to the class.

The answer comes from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62060345/1067293

- Place the mouse cursor over an unused argument and hit Alt+Enter.
- Then hit the right arrow and select "Run inspection on..."

[image: Run Inspection on...]

- On the new floating window select the file scope.

[image]

- The inspection panel will appear on the bottom.
- On the left select the file.
- Then on the right, click the "Add field to class" button.

[image]

It's a little bit too elaborate, but nonetheless comes in handy when you've more than a few args.

Answer (score 0):

A bit later but i think i find a solution, not sure if there is a short way but my solution is to put the args in the init like `$args$` or something like that, and below the init definition where the instance variables must be put something like `$argsSplit$` and in the expression of that variable put the following code:

```
groovyScript("def result = ''; _1.split(', ').each{ item -> result = result + 'self.' + item + ' = ' + item + System.lineSeparator() + '        '}; return result;", args)
```

[image: screenshot]