# PyCharm - generate fields for all constructor parameters

Tags: python, pycharm, code-generation

I define a class with constructor:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        ...
```

Now I want to declare a field for each constructor parameter, like this:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

I want to do this automatically. PyCharm's inspection allows me to generate fields for the parameters, but only one at a time (as a fix for `Parameter x is not used`), which is very annoying. How can I do this, for all parameters, simultaneously?

The closest thing I found is [PyCharm template for python class __init__ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114251/pycharm-template-for-python-class-init-function), and the solution is not flexible, since it supports only fixed number of parameters. Moreover, I feel like this is the feature which must be implemented in mature IDE, and Idea allows one to do this.

That post also references [What is the best way to do automatic attribute assignment in Python, and is it a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652851/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-automatic-attribute-assignment-in-python-and-is-it-a), which discusses `autoassign`, which seem to have lots of drawbacks.

My PyCharm version is 2019.1.3 CE.

Comment: yes, one at a time. https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tips/constructor-fields/

Answer (score 16):

The closest I have come to dealing with this is to write all your arguments in the function:

```py
class Xyz:
    def __init__(a, b, c):
```

highlight one argument, Right click, then click "**Show Context Actions**"

it should show "**Add field 'a' to Class Xyz**" then click the arrow ► 
and click "**Run Inspection on ...**"

Specify the Inspection scope to just that file or class.

Then your Class/File should appear in the inspection results window, click the drop down arrow and highlight the parameters and you should be able to "**Add fields to class Xyz**" which will add **all** the ones you select.

```py
class Xyz:
    def __init__(a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

Comment: Awesome! it worked, such a time saver