# Should i use dataclass to automatically initialize instance variables?

Tags: python, class-variables, data-class

I always want to shorten my code, for those classes have lots of variables, writing `init` method is time consuming.

There are few solutions for it to automatically initialize instance variables.
[Automatically initialize instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389180/automatically-initialize-instance-variables)

Since Python 3.7+, there is one more solution is to use `dataclass`, but since Python have shared variables during instances [How to avoid having class data shared among instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances)

So using dataclass to do automatic attribute assignment can be considered as good practice or it's only suitable for data-classes only?

Comment: Python doesn't share instance variables between instances. Regardless, `dataclass`es should be fine if you want to use them.

Comment: @martineau i found out that `dataclass` can't have list variable for avoiding mutable default argument problem

Comment: @TomSawyer Sure you can; you just have to use `default_factory` instead of assigning an actual empty list. `foo: List[int] = field(default_factory=list)`.

Comment: @tom: There's something in this [`dataclass` tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-data-classes/) explaining how to handle mutable default values with a `default_factory` in the section titled **Advanced Default Values**.