# passing all init variables to self

Tags: python, oop

Is there a standard way to pass all arguments defined in `__init__()` to the whole class (as self arguments)?

For example in my program I usually do it like this:

```
class DummyClass():
   def __init__(self,x,y,z):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.z = z
      ...
```

Is there a way to do the same without individually passing each argument? I think I saw once a similar thing with `super()`.

Comment: Yes that can be done using some tricks, but that's not recommended better write clean code. 
And if your requirement is, initialising these same variables inside multiple classes, then definitely you can use inheritance , using `super` keyword.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought that there was a common method that I didn't know of. Maybe the recommendation is to not extend too much with a high quantity of initialization variables?

Comment: In such case you can use python's `dataclass` decorator (works  with python3.7 or above) as suggested by @Tom McLean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1389304/14720380) answer you can do this:

```
class X(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        vars = locals() # dict of local names
        self.__dict__.update(vars) # __dict__ holds and object's attributes
        del self.__dict__["self"] # don't need `self`
```

A more pythonic answer is to use a dataclass

```
@dataclass
class X:
    x: float
    y: float
    z: float
```

Comment: I didn't know about dataclass, definitely useful.

Comment: Very usefull, checkout Pydantic as well