# Why does my Python class claim that I have 2 arguments instead of 1?

Tags: python, class-method

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import os
import stat
import sys
class chkup:

        def set(file):
                filepermission = os.stat(file)
                user_read()
                user_write()
                user_exec()

        def user_read():
                """Return True if 'file' is readable by user 
            """
            # Extract the permissions bits from the file's (or
            # directory's) stat info.
                b = bool(filepermission.st_mode & stat.S_IRUSR)
                print b
            return b

        def user_write():
                """Return True if 'file' is readable by user 
            """
            # Extract the permissions bits from the file's (or
            # directory's) stat info.
                b = bool(filepermission.st_mode & stat.S_WRUSR)
                print b
            return b

        def user_exec():
                """Return True if 'file' is readable by user 
            """
            # Extract the permissions bits from the file's (or
            # directory's) stat info.
                b = bool(filepermission.st_mode & stat.S_IXUSR)
                print b
            return b

def main():
        i = chkup()
        place = '/net/home/f08/itsrsw1/ScriptingWork/quotacheck'
        i.set(place)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

With that code I receive

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chkup.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "chkup.py", line 43, in main
    i.set(place)
TypeError: set() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first argument for a python class method is the `self` variable. If you call `classInstance.method(parameter)`, the method is invoked as `method(self, parameter)`.

So, when you're defining your class, do something like this:

```
class MyClass(Object): 
    def my_method(self, parameter): 
        print parameter
```

You might want to read through the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: Thanks all, I forgot about that. This the first actual class I've created with Python, so thanks for the patience. I started on Java so currently this feels pretty different!

Comment: Yeah, I remember having similar issues when I first started working with Python classes (not to mention being slightly annoyed that I had to explicitly write "self" everywhere). The hardest part about going python is learning to forget all of the cruft that you learned from Java or C++ :)

Answer (score 4):

Because you're not passing the object (generally referred to as `self`) as the first parameter to your methods. In Python, a call like this:

```
my_obj.do_something(my_other_obj)
```

is essentially desugared into a call like this:

```
MyClass.do_something(my_obj, my_other_obj)
```

Thus, Python is looking for a method signature like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def do_something(self, my_other_obj):
        self.my_var = my_other_obj
```

So you should pass the object (generally called `self`) as the first parameter to a *method*.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly pass `self` variable, which represents an instance of a class, e.g.:

```
def set(self, file):
    filepermission = os.stat(file)
    self.user_read()
    self.user_write()
    self.user_exec()
```

It doesn't have to be called `self` but it's a good convention to follow, and your code will be understood by other programmers.

Comment: That should be **self**.user_read(), **self**.user_write() etc.

Comment: Thanks, atzz, of course it's only correct for the same-class methods

Answer (score 1):

`self` is an implicit first argument to all class member functions. So the `i.set(place)` call actually calls `set(i, place)`. You need to take this into account when defining your class, and write `def set(self, file)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`set()` is a method of class `chkup`. When you call `i.set(place)`, python keeps track of the instance i using the first argument to the method. Generally, every instance method will receive at least one argument, called self, and subsequent arguments follow. You should redefine your class:

```
class chkup:
    def set(self, file):
        "etc..."
```

You might look up "self" and python on stackoverflow:

[Python __init__ and self what do they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do)

etc.

Answer (score 0):

In a class, you need to take into account the `self` parameter for method members.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're treating `set` as a bound (instance) method of a class, you must explicitly receive the instance as your first argument. It's called "self" by convention.

```
def set(self, file):
    filepermission = os.stat(file)
    user_read()
    user_write()
    user_exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to define a non-static method you must provide "self" as a first argument like this

class chkup:

```
    def set(self,file):
            filepermission = os.stat(file)
```

#this is done to make non static methods,

#the call of set() here done by

chk=chkup()

chk.set(fileName) # note that you dont provide "self" when calling

Answer (score 0):

Thats because python automatically passes the current object as an argument to all the methods in the class,so when you pass 2 arguments to a function,python appends the third argument which is the current object,the method prototype should consider this