# Python how to pass variable between two def

Tags: python, global-variables, environment-variables

I would pass a variable between two def inside a function. How can i do? i tried using global but didn't work

```
class example:

 def funz1(self,q,b):
    global queue
    queue = []
    queue += [q]
    queue += [a]

 def funz2(self):
    return str(queue.pop())
```

but it said me that queue is an empty list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `self` parameter, which points to the `example` instance itself:

```
class example:    
 def funz1(self,q,b):
    self.queue = []
    self.queue += [q]
    self.queue += [a]

 def funz2(self):
    return str(self.queue.pop())
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do).

Also, as a side note, `array += [item]` is wrong, you should use `array.append(item)`

Comment: but self has no attribute 'queue'

Comment: @fege you create on the `self.queue = []` line

Comment: if i want pass the variable between the def without the class?

Comment: in self of funz1 i have a list so when i run your code it answer me 'list' object has no attribute 'queue'

Answer (score 1):

There are several issued with that code, first, there is no need to use a global bar since you can access self. Also, pop will raise an exception if the list is not empty, therefore, you can have the following:

```
class example:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []

    def funz1(self,q,b):
        self.queue.append(q)
        self.queue.append(b)

    def funz2(self):
        if len(self.queue) > 0:
            return str(self.queue.pop())
```

On top of that, if you are using a list as a q you might as well use deque from collections which was designed for that use:

```
from collections import deque

class example:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = deque()

    def funz1(self,q,b):
        self.queue.append(q)
        self.queue.append(b)

    def funz2(self):
        if len(self.queue) > 0:
            return str(self.queue.popleft())
```