# ctypes strings defined in a ctype structure don't work

Tags: python, string, ctypes

I'm having a bit of a problem creating a ctypes structure with a string in it and initializing it with a meaningful value.

Here's my structure:

```
class MyStruct( Structure ):
    _fields_ = [ ("someString", c_char_p) ]
```

and here's me trying to initialize it

```
obj = MyStruct( "something" )
```

Both attempts fail of course. Here's the error message:

> obj_1= MyStruct( "something" )
>   TypeError: string or integer address expected instead of str instance

Same thing happens if I use *c_char_p* operator
    obj = MyStruct( c_char_p( "something" ) )

I must mention that this code is executed in Blender 2.63a environment.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [`__init__` method to instantiate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do):

```
class MyStruct( Structure ):
    def __init__(self,some_string):
         self._fields_ = [ (some_string, c_char_p) ]
```

Then to make a new Structure, should work:

```
obj = MyStruct( "something" )
```

Comment: @Paksas, you should accept the best answer by selecting the check to the left and upvoting any helpful answers.  It's the SO way of rewarding the people that help you.