# Use `object` to instantiate custom class

Tags: python

here is my haha  class

```
class  haha(object):
  def  theprint(self):
    print "i am here"

>>> haha().theprint()
i am here
>>> haha(object).theprint()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

why `haha(object).theprint()` get wrong output?

Comment: What are you expecting `haha(object)` to do?

Comment: OP is confusing inheritance with instantiation

Comment: Although this is a novice question, I think the author is making a best attempt at asking it well, and it's an understandable confusion. Not grounds for a downvote, in my book.

Answer (score 0):

`class haha(object):` means that `haha` inherits from `object`. Inheriting from `object` basically means that it's a new-style class.

Calling `haha()` creates a new instance of `haha` and thus calls the *constructor* which would be a method named `__init__`. However, you do not have one so the defaul constructor is used which does not accept any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This example of a slight change of your `haha` may help you to understand what is happening. I've implemented [`__init__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do) so you can see when it is called.

```
>>> class haha(object):
...   def __init__(self, arg=None):
...     print '__init__ called on a new haha with argument %r' % (arg,)
...   def theprint(self):
...     print "i am here"
... 
>>> haha().theprint()
__init__ called on a new haha with argument None
i am here
>>> haha(object).theprint()
__init__ called on a new haha with argument <type 'object'>
i am here
```

As you can see, `haha(object)` ends up passing `object` as a parameter to `__init__`. Since you hadn't implemented `__init__`, you were getting an error because the default `__init__` does not accept parameters. As you can see, it doesn't make much sense to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing Inheritance with initializing a class when instantiate.

In this case, for your class declaration, you should do

```
class  haha(object):
    def  theprint(self):
        print "i am here"

>>> haha().theprint()
i am here
```

Because haha(object) means that haha inherits from object. In python, there is no need to write this because all classes inherits from object by default.

If you have an **init** method which receives parameters, you need to pass those arguments when instantiating, for example

```
class  haha():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
    def theprint(self):
        print 'hi %s i am here' % self.name

>>> haha('iferminm').theprint()
hi iferminm i am here
```