# understanding why constructors take arguments?

Tags: python, constructor

I am able to understand what constructors are. But why can't python take initializer lists like c++?

```
class test:
     def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
         self.arg1 = arg1
         self.arg2 = arg2
         self.arg3 = arg3
```

how will those arguments ever be set without being so manual?

Thanks.

Comment: Can a human have time to enter the desired arguments to any other function/method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do -- just to be sure that you *"understand what constructors are"*

Comment: Please don't make such radical changes to a question. Open up a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
test1 = test(1, 2, 3)
```

A constructor is just like any old function, and you pass arguments to it.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is called once the object is created, not once it is called:

```
t = test (arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple - when you instantiate the class later on:

```
a = test(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

`a` is now a test class, with the 3 arguments set when you initialised it.

Comment: @CasparWylie you can't have more than one constructor.

Comment: The `__init__` is called when you initialise the object - you can't have more than one `__init__` by definition.

Comment: Those arguments probably have default values (Or will be `None` if not set). `def __init__(self, arg1=2, arg2=3)` will default `arg1,2` to `2,3` respectively if you don't manually set them.

Comment: And what is the definition of Page1/2/3?

Comment: ok, here is the whlre script: http://pastebin.com/fC1sxr18 thanks for all the help

Comment: Page1/2/3 don't need any specific arguments - the code passes `self` (The main tk.Frame object) as the sole argument. To clarify - `*args` is any positional arguments you'd pass (`Page1(1, 2, 3) -> *args is (1, 2, 3)`), and `**kwargs` is any named arguments (`Page2(b=2, c=3) -> **kwargs is a dict {'b':2, 'c':3}`)

Answer (score 0):

The intention behind this is to directly initialize some variables passed to the constructor. The constructor is, as written several times before, called:

```
t = test(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

You have then for the passed parameters defined values in your class.