# print to console in PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, console, pydev

I'm a newbie to PyDev in Eclipse. 
When coding simple programs, I use print() statements regularly in order to track the values of variables. I want these values to be printed to the console but I couldn't get any value printed in the console so far.

Here's a simple piece of code to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

```
class MyClass(object):

  def __init__(self):

    myClassObject= MyClass()
    myClassObject.greet()


    def greet(self):
       print("stackoverflow is the best !!!")
```

I'm expecting to see the string "*stackoverflow is the best !!!*" in the console but when I run the code I get nothing at all. What am I supposed to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code is evaluated when you call it.

Comment: Okay, there was the confusion of not instantiating a class object in my question and I fixed it. Please be noted that the problem is not with initializing an object instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not instantiated the class. In order to produce output from what you've got try the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  instance = MyClass()
```

-- REVISED --

In light of your rewritten code, you should have the following:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #myClassObject= MyClass() # Causes recursion error.
        #myClassObject.greet() # You should not be accessing your instance method this way
        self.greet()


    def greet(self):
        print("stackoverflow is the best !!!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    instance = MyClass()
```

Your example appears to be overly complicated. You would do well to review class usage in Python for [Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html) or [Python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':` comes when I use a Module:main. But within a class I have the main method instead. (i.e. `def __init__(self):`)
When I use a main module everything works fine but the problem occurs when I print() inside __init__(self) .
I instantiated an object but still the console is blank. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` is called when the class is instantiated (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do)). Adding `my_instance = MyClass()` at the end of your snippet will create an instance of the `MyClass` class and should print out what you want:

```
class MyClass(object):

  def __init__(self):
    print("stackoverflow is the best !!!")

my_instance = MyClass()
```

Comment: Are you able to `print` anything at all? Or is it just this example that doesn't work?

Comment: well I tried, unfortunately it doesn't work

`class MyClass(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        my_class= MyClass()
        my_class.greet()
    
    def greet(self):
        print("Hello World")
`

Comment: Yes @mtth , that was my worry, I couldn't print anything

Comment: Without the formatting and indentation, it's hard to see what is going on. I added an example, is that what you had tried?
Edit - it seems to be a problem with your console then, maybe it silences print statements.

Comment: I noticed that this problem occurs only when I write a class.
When I use a new main **Module:main**, it works fine and the console prints whatever written inside `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: Does that mean you are defining your class in a separate module? If that is the case, maybe it isn't getting imported.

Comment: Yes I'm defining **MyClass** in a module named **MyClass.py**. There's nothing to import, the whole code is inside the MyClass.py module itself

Answer (score 0):

I just learnt that my code portion in the question was meaningless because I have instantiated the objects in `__init__(self)`. So the object has to be created inside a `if __name__ == '__main__':` instead.

I have written a complete module to demonstrate this. (Observe there are multiple classes in Classes.py module and then it is imported in the second part of the code)

```
'''
Classes.py
'''


class MyClass(object):  


    def greet(self):
        print("Hello World")


class MyNextClass(object):

        def greetAgain(self):
            print("Hello again")
```

---

```
'''
MyMain.py
'''
import Classes

if __name__ == '__main__':

    a=Classes.MyClass()
    a.greet()

    b=Classes.MyNextClass();
    b.greetAgain()
```

The above code makes sense and it will output to the console without problems.