# Sublime Editor Plugin remember variable

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2

I am writing a sublime editor 2 plugin, and would like it to remember a variable for the duration of the session. I do not want it to save the variable as a file (it is a password), but would like to be able to run a command repeatedly, and the variable to be accessible.

I want my plugin to work something like this...

```
import commands, subprocess

class MyCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
  def run(self, edit, command = "ls"):
    try:
      thevariable
    except NameError:
      # should run the first time only
      thevariable = "A VALUE"
    else:
      # should run subsequent times
      print thevariable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to make it a global variable. This will allow you to access that variable from any function. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them) is a stack question to consider.

Another option would be to add it to the instance of the class. This is commonly done in the `__init__()` method of the class. This method is run as soon as the class object is instantiated. For more information on `self` and `__init__()` consult [this stack discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do).  Here is a basic example.

```
class MyCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view # EDIT
        self.thevariable = 'YOUR VALUE'
```

This will allow you to access this variable from a class object after it has been created. Something like this `MyCommandObject.thevariable`. These types of variables will last until the window in which the method was called from is closed.

Comment: I like the idea, seems like exactly what I want, but I am getting an error `AttributeError: 'ConsoleLogCommand' object has no attribute 'view'`