# Error occured while callling a class in another module by using importlib in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to call a module with `mod = importlib.import_module(str)` from `Sample2.py` and the module which

I am calling is `PlayAround_Play.py` it is working fine when it contains only a function . If I included a class to that function

It is not working fine. Getting error as `TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments`

### code in sample2.py

```
import importlib
def calling():
      str="PlayAround_Play" 
      a=10
      b=20
      c=30
      mod = importlib.import_module(str)
      getattr(mod,str)(a, b, c)    

calling()
```

### code in PlayAround_Play.py

```
class PlayAround_Play():
        def PlayAround_Play(self, a, b, c):
              d=a+b+c
              print d
```

can u guys show me a solution how to call that class by using `importlib`

Comment: That's because the constructor method is always named `__init__`, it isn't named after the class... How do you know about importlib and getattr but don't know basics about python classes?

Comment: ... Well, after reading your other questions it's pretty clear that you don't know anything about python and only got this code from other people as answers to your previous question. Please get a basic understanding of the language by reading the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) before asking further questions.

Comment: tried with different names also getting same error..

Comment: yes.. i dont know about python language learning now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling your class incorrectly, correct way:

```
inst = getattr(mod, strs)()   #creates an instance of the class
inst.PlayAround_Play(a, b, c) #call `PlayAround_Play` method on the instance.
```

**Output:**

```
60
```

---

To make your code work fine define `__init__` in your class:

```
class PlayAround_Play():

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        d = a+b+c
        print d
```

Now:

```
getattr(mod, strs)(a, b, c)
#prints 60
```

Read:

- [Python `__init__` and `self` what do they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do)
- [Python classes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: That seems like a bad use of `__init__`, using a print statement instead of initialization.