# Why do I get "Typeerror: object.__new__() takes no parameters"?

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm simply trying to make a code that generates dice (in python).
Here's the code:

```
import random

class Dice:
     def _init_(self, number_dice):
          self._dice = [6] * number_dice

     def roll_dice(self):
          for d in range(len(self._dice)):
               self._dice[d] = random.randit(1, 6)
          self._dice.sort()

     def print_roll(self):
          length = len(self._dice)
          print(str(lenth) + "dice:" + str(self._dice))



my_dice = Dice(2)
my_dice.roll_dice()
my_dice.print_roll()
```

The compiler says something about line 18.

Comment: " something about" - would be helpful to copy the error message too.,

Answer (score 11):

You need *two* underscores before and after `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, number_dice):
    self._dice= [6] *number_dice
```

Otherwise, Python treats that method as a custom one and not the special [`__init__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do) constructor method.

Comment: Fun fact: The double underscore pattern is called the "dunder".

Answer (score 5):

You should replace `_init_` with `__init__`