# Why in tkinter you don't have to write init?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I'm using Pygame, a python library, I have to write "pygame.init" to initiate all modules. However, when I'm using Tkinter, **another library**, I don't have to use "tkinter.init". Why?
Thanks!

Comment: Go to this link i think a couple of people have awsnered this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444517/init-in-gui-with-tkinter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When I'm using Pygame, a python library, I have to write "pygame.init()" to initiate all modules. However, when I'm using Tkinter, another library, I don't have to use "tkinter.init()". Why?*

**Each Python library comes with its own way of using it and own mechanisms implemented for event handling if the library provides methods for interacting with the user.**

How to use the library is then explained in the documentation or can be inferred from the documentation coming along with each library method and printed on demand.

*So the right answer to the question why you have to use the library this and not other way is as simple as maybe surprising:*

**Because the library requires to use it this and not other way.**

By the way:

- in Tkinter (newer versions of the module are named tkinter) the initialization is silently done within an initialization method `__init__` of the class Tk when creating the root window with `root = tkinter.Tk()` *and* for the tkinter window coming up you need in addition to this initialization `tkinter.mainloop()`.

Here a minimal tkinter code required to open a window (see comments for details/explanations):

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
tkinter.mainloop()
# ^-- requires root = tkinter.Tk() else:  
# ^-- RuntimeError: Too early to run the main loop: no default root window
```

- in pygame it is not necessary to call `pygame.init()` to open a pygame window.

Here a minimal pygame code required to open a window, keep it opened and responding (see comments for details/explanations):

```
import pygame
# pygame.init()
# ^-- is NOT required
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480)) 
# ^-- REQUIRED else: pygame.error: video system not initialized
# ^-- creates the pygame window which stays opened (but not responding)
# ^--    as long as the Python script runs

# v--REQUIRED to keep the pygame window opened and responding: 
running = True
while running:
    # Check for exit: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```