# Python Class Runtime-Error

Tags: python, class, runtime-error

I have just started python and made a program about 8 line of code which only calculates the area of a triangle but when ever I try running it, I would get this error

> File "", line 1, in 
>       t.Area(12,12) line 3, in Area
>       length = self.num1 AttributeError: 'Triangle' object has no attribute 'num1'

And here is my code

```
class Triangle:
    def Area(self,num1,num2):
        length = self.num1
        width = self.num2
        area = (length * width) / 2
        area = int(area)
        print("Your area is: %s " %area)
```

help would be appreciated

Comment: I see you have some answers on C++. Think of `self` as Python's `this`, only that instead of being implicit it's always explicitly there. So, in your case, it makes no sense to write `self.num1`, as `num1` is an argument to the function

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. In your own words, why have you created a `Triangle` class, instead of just writing the function by itself?

Answer (score 1):

As the message states: Your object does not feature an attribute `num1` (and moreover no attribute `num2`). You need to set these somewhere in your class, i.e.

```
class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        #set length and width of triangle at instantiation
        self.length = num1
        self.width = num2

    def Area(self):
        #and all the other stuff here...
```

On the other hand, your method looks like you want to pass the two values `num1` and `num2`. In that case, you just need to remove `self.` in front of the assumed attributes, since you are passing the values  as arguments:

```
class Triangle:
    def Area(self,num1,num2):
        length = num1
        width = num2
        #and all the other stuff here...
```

Of course, you might as well cut `num1` and `num2` directly in this case:

```
class Triangle:
    def Area(self,length,width):
        #and all the other stuff here...
```

Comment: That is not how you set object attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the variables be members of the class before you can use them via the `self.num1` syntax. Before you specify `self.num1` there is no `num1` contained in your `Triangle` class. Specifically a class needs to have a way of initializing the members it contains. You can do this by creating a constructor with `__init__` which gets called when you make an instance of `Triangle`. That approach would look something like this:

```
class Triangle:
    def __init__(self,num1,num2):
        self.width = num1 #now num1 is associated with your instance of Triangle
        self.length = num2

    def Area(self):#note: no need for num1 and num2 anymore
        area = (self.length * self.width) / 2
        print("Your area is: %s " % int(area))
```

Alternatively you can define those members within a different method (as in not `__init__`) like this

```
class Triangle:
    def SetDimensions(self,length,witdh):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width

    def Area(self):
        area = (self.length * self.width) / 2
        print("Your area is: %s " %int(area))
```

For more info about what `self` and `__init__` do I'd recommend having a look at: [Python __init__ and self what do they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do).
If the `Area` method really has nothing to do with a particular instance and you just want to have a general purpose way of finding the area of a right angled triangle then a free function might be a better approach:

```
def RightAngleTriangleArea(self,length,width):
    area = (length * width) / 2
    area = int(area)
    print("Your area is: %s " %area)
```

Note that there's far better ways to actually specify a data type for a triangle if you do decide to go the route of a `Triangle` class.

Comment: There is no point in passing `num1` and `num2` to the method `Area` in your code example. These values would not be used.

Comment: And if you are going to introduce `__init__` you may as well model the triangle more sensibly ... `__init__(self, sideA, sideB, angleAB)` or whatnot

Comment: Why would one want to assign values to attributes within a method of a class that is supposed to handle a different task? This is not an example of well-arranged code.

Comment: @pyStarter: I just tried to address the syntax issue initially but as I answered I realized the design needed a lot of attention.

Comment: @wim, sure there's far better ways of modelling a triangle, I'm more than aware of that. I just wanted to address the python-specific error message in the original question.