# The missing argument

Tags: python, class

I have a class like following

```
class A:
     def __init__(self:A,size:int):
        self.size=size
```

when I input like:

```
>>>a=A(5)    
>>>a.size
```

it will come

```
>>>5
```

However when I input like:

```
>>>A.__init__(5)
```

it will have an missing argument 'size' error. I just don't understand that, Why I entered an init it still missing argument?

Comment: `(self:A,size:int)` can't be.

Comment: `self:A` should raise an error, as `A` is not defined when `__init__` gets defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__init__` needs a two arguments, `self` and an integer. Isn't that so simple?

For instance methods, Python will automatically pass a reference of the instance to your function. This is why all instance methods needs at least one argument, `self`.

This is your case:

```
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self)::

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Created!")


>>> a = A()
Created! #Success
>>> b = A.__init__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    b = A.__init__()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Well, no wonder. `__init__` needs an argument, but you're not passing anything.

However, if you insist on calling the function, you can just use another instance:

```
>>> b = A.__init__(a)
Created!
```

However this is just calling the function, and no new instance will be produced. `b` is `None`.

Comment: @ editor: Thanks, but that would be  a good comment for the OP.

Comment: Ok I get this. but when I entered A.__init__(5) why its missing the size argument not self?

Comment: Because the arguments are positional; it assumes that the first is `self`, so `size` must be missing.

Answer (score 1):

`__init__` is the constructor function in Python; read the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do) which explain  in detail that concept.

In order to call a function (or "method") on a class in Python you need a classmethod; this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12179752/1211429) explains the role of `classmethod` vs instance methods in Python.

The main distinction is that:

- for class methods the class is passed as the first argument to the `classmethod`,
- for instance methods, the instance itself is passed as the first argument to the method