# What information is __init__.storing?

Tags: python, class, object, init, self

I read somewhere that `__init__` stores information while creating the object. So, let's say I have this code:

```
class BankAccount(object):
    def __init__(self, deposit):
        self.amount = deposit 

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.amount -= amount

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.amount += amount

    def balance(self):
        return self.amount 

myAccount = BankAccount(16.20)

x = raw_input("What would you like to do?")

if x == "deposit":    
    myAccount.deposit(int(float(raw_input("How much would you like to deposit?"))))
    print "Total balance is: ", myAccount.balance()   
elif x == "withdraw":    
    myAccount.withdraw(int(float(raw_input("How much would you like to withdraw?"))))
    print "Total balance is: ", myAccount.balance()    
else:
    print "Please choose 'withdraw' or 'deposit'. Thank you."
```

What is `__init__` doing or storing. I don't understand what "self.amount" is or how making it = deposit does anything. Is the "self.amount" under `__init__` the same as the one under `withdraw`? I'm just not understanding what "self_amount" does.

Comment: It has been explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods

Comment: @Christian I've currently been using learnpythonthehardway and I've been on many websites and read many things and haven't found the answer to my question. It's why I came here.

Comment: If your misunderstanding is about just what `self.amount` does, you should try to come up with a much simpler example.  Try to come up with the simplest example that you don't understand.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q** What is `__init__` doing or storing?

**A** `__init__` gets called whenever you construct an instance of the class. This applies to all classes. It is customary to initialize all your data in this function. In your particular case, you are creating a member data called `amount` and assigning it to be the same as the `deposit` argument passed to the function.

**Q** I don't understand what `"self.amount"` is or how making it `= deposit` does anything.

**A** The statement `self.amount = deposit` accomplishes couple of things. It creates a member data of the class named `amount` and assigns it to be the value of `deposit`.

**Q** Is the `"self.amount"` under `__init__` the same as the one under withdraw?

**A** Yes.

**Q** I'm just not understanding what `"self.amount"` does.

**A** It allows you to capture the data of the object. Every class needs to figure out  member data it needs to work correctly. In your case, the only data you need is the `amount`. If you had a class called `Employee`, it might look something like:

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, id, salary):
        self.firstName = firstName 
        self.lastName = lastName 
        self.id = id 
        self.salary = salary
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python, [`__init__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) is a method called when a instance of the class is created. This method is usually used to *initialize* instance variables. After initializing, you can use them in other methods.

About `self.amount`, it's an instance variable (there are class variables too). In other words an attribute.

Your class is `BankAccount`, each bank account should have an amount. That's when instance variables become helpful!

When you create an instance

```
myAccount = BankAccount(16.20)
```

the `__init__()` method is called, (you can see this by putting a `print` inside), and it will set `self.amount` with `16.20`.

Comment: Oh adding the print helped me a lot. My issue was where it said: self.amount = deposit, I didn't realize I could just change "deposit" to "amount" and it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

From your question I think you are new to object-oriented programming (OOP).
I suggest reading about it, and how it is implemented in Python.
Here is a short starting point: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Then feel free to search about the new concepts that you learned there.

In short, to get directly to the point of your question:

- Classes are object templates;
- An object that implements such a template is called a instance of the class;
- Objects may have instance variables, which store a value specific to each instance;
- Classes may define a constructor, called when creating a instance of the class. These constructor are usually used to initialize the instance variables.
- In Python, all the methods of a class take the instance they work on as an argument, named `self` by convention
- In Python, `__init__` is the name of the constructor

So in Python when you call `myAccount.deposit(10)`, you could say it is equivalent to `BankAccount.deposit(myAccount, 10)`. So yes, the `self` variable is "the same" in all your four methods, and in your example it is assigned with `myAccount`.

Comment: @Christian You're right. I edited to make it more like an answer, hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You probably confusing **self.amount** with **amount**. **self.amount** is a variable associated with class **BankAccount**, it gets initialized when the instance of the class is created. So, self.amount is same everywhere in your class, but **amount** is an argument, so it depends on the value you give at function calling.
Read : http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html
and http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/OOP.shtml#the-init-method