# How to localize django_tables2 column names?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I have used django_tables2 in my web page to display a table.

My code for this table is in tables.py:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy
from django.utils.encoding import force_text

    class patchTable(tables.Table):
        release_version=tables.Column(verbose_name=force_text(ugettext_lazy("Release Version"),orderable=False, localize=True)
        patch_version=tables.Column(verbose_name=force_text(ugettext_lazy("Patch Version")),orderable=False, localize=True)
        release_date = tables.Column(verbose_name=force_text(ugettext_lazy("Release Date")),orderable=False, localize=True)
        upload_date = tables.Column(verbose_name=force_text(ugettext_lazy("Upload Date")),orderable=False, localize=True)
        apply_status = tables.Column(verbose_name=force_text(ugettext_lazy("Status")),orderable=False, localize=True)
        installation_date = tables.Column(verbose_name=force_text(ugettext_lazy("Installation Date")),orderable=False, localize=True)
```

In my views.py method i am doing "from myapp.tables import patchTable" and then updating the table contents,paginating and rendering to a template.

Above code works fine and displays the column name in a language which is currently i am using(during runserver command). but if i change the language selection on my HTML page all other contents on page gets translated but column name of this table doesn't.

If i restart the django server (cntrl+c and python2.7 manage runserver 0.0.0.0:8060) then these names changes to current language but they are not happening dynamically on language selection.

I tried using 1) "ugettext" 2) "ugettext_lazy" (this throws exception:'Lazy object returned unexpected type.)' 3) "force_text" and "ugettext_lazy" combination. But they are not working. Can anyone suggest me a feasible way of doing it?

By the way I am using Python 2.7, Django 1.5.1 and Django development server. All the localization settings requirement are included in project and settings.py has "USE_L10N = True" and "USE_I18N = True".
Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if this question needs much more details. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-wrote the code as,

```
class test():
    _name = None
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def __unicode__(self):
        english_string = get_string()
        params = {}
        params = deepcopy(english_string)
        var = force_text(params['patch_text'][self._name])
        return unicode(var )

class patchTable(tables.Table):

    release_version = tables.Column(verbose_name=test('release_version'),orderable=False)
    patch_version = tables.Column(verbose_name=test('patch_version'),orderable=False)
    release_date = tables.Column(verbose_name=test('release_date'),orderable=False)
    upload_date = tables.Column(verbose_name=test('upload_date'),orderable=False)
    apply_status = tables.Column(verbose_name=test('status'),orderable=False)
    installation_date = tables.Column(verbose_name=test('installation_date'),orderable=False)
    class Meta:
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue", "id":"patch_details", "style":"cursor: pointer;"}
        orderable = False
```

get_string() is a function that returns translated strings as key value pair. keys are nothing but the column names, values are their respective translated strings(changes on language selection). 
verbose name is defined by class test() which initializes column names for each new object. **init** with **unicode** helped me to solve this.

Thanks to  @ruddra and @VikasVerma, Your suggestions helped me.

Comment: Would you mind providing the get_string() function you used ?

Answer (score 1):

Under `class patchTable(tables.Table):`, please add this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(patchTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

`__init__` is a constructor, so when the class is called, an object of that Class will be created. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do).

Comment: It is an useful info. I defined this under my class. And saw that each time an object of that Class will be created. But still I am not getting translated strings for column headers. I tried passing translated strings from views.py method to __init__() function as args and tried assigning those to column attribute. But Still i didnt find a way to solve it.

Comment: under `super(patchTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` , try assigning translated string as attributes of column

Answer (score 1):

A general solution for tables based on a model:

```
class TranslatedTable(tables.Table):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TranslatedTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for column in self.base_columns:
            self.base_columns[column].verbose_name = \
                self.Meta.model._meta.get_field(column).verbose_name
```

The column headers will be defined by `verbose_name` of the corresponding field and properly translated. Note that `verbose_name` in this case should be decorated for translation in the model definition, for example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_("Name"))
```