# Ununderstood Python OOP error

Tags: python, oop

My code is:

```
import time
class Stopwatch (object):
    def start (self):
        self.beginningTime = time.time()
        self.fehlerzahl = 1
    def stop (self):
        self.endTime = time.time()
        self.time = self.endTime - self.beginningTime
    def fehler(self):
        self.fehlerzahl = self.fehlerzahl + 1;
    def getTime (self):
        return(self.time + self.fehlerzahl * 2)
```

When I call the fehler() (Function names are in German) funtction, python gives me the following error trace:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Mar  1 2013, 11:53:50) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import stopwatch
>>> c = stopwatch.Stopwatch()
>>> c.fehler()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "stopwatch.py", line 10, in fehler
    self.fehlerzahl = self.fehlerzahl + 1;
AttributeError: 'Stopwatch' object has no attribute 'fehlerzahl'
>>>
```

Please tell me why it doesn't run.

Thanks

Comment: You never `start`ed the stopwatch. In other words, you never set/initialized `self.fehlerzahl`, but you try to use its value in the `fehler` method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do may help: make use of `__init__()` to set attributes.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the `fehler()` function is trying to increment an attribute that doesn't exist yet.

From your code, the `start()` function is where the `fehlerzahl` attribute is defined. You'll have to call this function first before you call `fehler()`:

```
import stopwatch
c = stopwatch.Stopwatch()
c = stopwatch.start()
c.fehler()
```

Your variables need to be defined before you try to manipulate them. You can either call the `start()` function first or define the `fehlerzahl` earlier in the code; Perhaps in an `__init__` function.

From the [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172231/ununderstood-python-oop-error#comment42835086_27172301) it seems that an assumption was made that the `start()` function is the class constructor - this is not the case. A python class constructor is named `__init__` so essentially all that needs to be done is to change the function name `start` to `__init__`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Sorry for the stupid question. Actually I'm trying to code a whole project within 2 hours. I thought start() is the constructor ;-)

Comment: @Laurenz - coding under pressure :) Always fun! Glad to help, good luck and happy coding!

Comment: @Laurenz it's not, but you can make it one! Just add `__init__ = start` to your class definition.

Comment: @ch3ka - I wouldn't recommend overriding the `__init__` constructor like that. It would make more sense (and preserve readability) to use `__init__` as it was intended.

Comment: @Lix `__init__ = start` does not override anything, it's exactly the same as renaming `start` to `__init__` (minus the remaining alias).

Comment: @ch3ka - when reading the code of a class, a programmer will always look for the `__init__` function - it's something that everyone expects to exist - in order to make readable code the original name should be preserved. You're right, however that it doesn't make a difference to the actual behavior of the code; I'm referencing the readability and thinking of the next programmer 6 months later who would be looking at this code.

Comment: @Laurenz: And `stop` is not the destructor. In fact, there is no real destructor in Python (`__del__` doesn't count).

Comment: @Lix I well see your point, and you're right in that one should not really teach such practise; but OTOH relying on that function/method definitions always start with `def` is just plain wrong. Functions are first order citizens for a very good reason, and `lambda` exists, too.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `start()` on the stopwatch.