# Python garbage collector

Tags: python, garbage-collection

Given the code sample below, what is the life cycle for `bb` in in example 1 and for `self.bb` in example 2

Example 1

```
import B

class A:
    def __init__( self ):
        bb = B( self )
```

Example 2

```
import B

class A:

    def __init__( self ):
        self.bb = B( self )
```

Edit:

B is another class and for some reason i found it was not garbage collected in the first example. I looked more carefully in my code and i found out B class created a new class C and gave a ref to one of its methods to that C class. In the end C instantiated a loop back thread to wait for events hence B class instance was still alive even though A class init was done.

Thanks all for your answers.

Comment: Neither `bb` has **any** lifetime, since you are not creating instances of class A. `bb` in the first example is a local; like all locals it is cleaned up the moment `A.__init__` exits. Your question is rather broad and answered in the Python documentation and elsewhere on Stack Overflow though; what research have you done yourself and what wasn't clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On both cases there will be no reference to the `B` instance until you instantiate `A`.

Once you instantiate `A`, in the first case it will be discarded right after `__init__` runs because `bb` will be out of scope and there will be no reference left to that `B` instance, so it will be garbage-collected on the next GC cycle (exactly when is an implementation detail). On the second case, the reference to that `B` instance will exist as long as a reference for the `A` instance exists or until you manually remove it.

Comment: In CPython, objects go away the moment their reference count drops to 0. The GC only deals with *circular references*, which doesn't apply here. So the object is reaped *instantly*, not in the next GC cycle. But Jython, IronPython and PyPy are free to use different strategies, and do so.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This comment you made saved my day. Thanks!!!

Comment: And in Jython, say, there is no guarantee that the garbage is *ever* collected.

Answer (score 0):

In first example `bb` is `local variable` for function `__init__` The `bb` variable can access within the same `__init__` function.

In 2nd example `self.bb` is `Instance variables` for every class object.

Answer (score -2):

They has not any life-time. You have to inherited.

```
Example 1

import B
class A:
    def __init__( self ):
        B.__init__(self)
bb = B()

Example 2

import B
class A:
    def __init__( self ):
        B.__init__(self)

bb = B()
```

For more information about [**init**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do)