# Classes usage && inheritance: am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, class, oop, python-2.7

I just start experimenting with OOP in **Python** 2.7.

Here is example of code, which I currently writing for my project. 
This is just 'template' - not real code fron app, but this app will use same classes "scheme", as in example below.

I'd like to know - what I'm doing incorrect here? Classes initialization, some wrong inheritance usage, other mistakes?

It works, but - may be I'm wrong with some 'ideological' points?

Files: `main.py` - programm body; `cl1.py` - *First* class; `cl2.py` - *Second* class.

`main.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cl1, cl2

print('\nStarted Main script.\n')

cl1 = cl1.First()
cl1.one('This is first_arg')

cl2 = cl2.Second()
cl2.two('This is second arg')
```

`cl1.py`:

```
class First:

    def one(self, first_arg):

        self.third_arg = 'This is third arg from First class'

        self.first_arg = first_arg
        print('This is method \'one\' from class First.\nWork with first_arg = %s\n' % self.first_arg)
```

`cl2.py`:

```
from cl1 import First

class Second(First):

    def two(self, second_arg):

        self.second_arg = second_arg
        print('This is method \'two\' from class Second.\nWork with second_arg = %s\n' % self.second_arg)

        self.one('I came from Second.two() to First.one()')

        print('I came from First.one() as self.third_arg to Second.two(): %s\n' % self.third_arg)
```

Result:

```
$ ./main.py

Started Main script.

This is method 'one' from class First.
Work with first_arg = This is first_arg

This is method 'two' from class Second.
Work with second_arg = This is second arg

This is method 'one' from class First.
Work with first_arg = I came from Second.two() to First.one()

I came from First.one() as self.third_arg to Second.two(): This is third arg from First class
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? What do you mean by `ideological`? From here, it seems to me that you subclass from another class and define extra methods in it. What's wrong?

Comment: May be better was  post it to CR?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create properties of a class *on-the-fly* in its method. A class should know which properties it inherited from the super class upon initialization. You should create instance variables only in the [`__init__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do), a special constructor method.

```
class First(object):
    def __init__(self, first_arg):
        self.first_arg = first_arg

    @property
    def one(self):
        return self.first_arg

    @one.setter
    def one(self, value):
        self.first_arg = value
```

---

```
>>> first = First(5)
>>> print first.one
5
>>> first.one = 10
>>> print first.one
10
```

---

If you want to add an extra property to `First` class by creating a new  class called `Second`, you should always first inherit the super class's properties in the subclass's constructor:

```
class Second(First):
    def __init__(self, first_arg, second_arg):
        super(Second, self).__init__(first_arg) # now you have "self.first_arg"
        self.second_arg = second_arg

    @property
    def two(self):
        return self.second_arg

    @two.setter
    def two(self, value):
        self.second_arg = value
```

---

```
>>> second = Second(7, 10)
>>> print second.one
7
>>> print second.two
10
>>> second.two = 20
>>> second.one = 15
...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

### I will quickly name your problems in this code:

Your naming variables go like one, two, cl1, cl2. **Those are senseless and are HARD to understand, especially for beginners like you**. It is way easier for you to think of some real world example and try to build a structure for that.

Personally, I always create classes about games which I play, so that way everything seems logical and easy to learn for me.

**Example:** You are playing Call of Duty. Then you would have the following classes: Soldier, Civilian, Weapon, Map and so on.
Soldier would have methods:

- Soldier.Run()
- Soldier.Shoot()
- Soldier.ReloadWeapon()

And AmericanSoldier and GermanSoldier would all inherit the base Soldier class and it is all logical (and fun) to code!

I am yet to learn a new programming language using the moronic exampless of autist guides with "Var_1, Var_2" which a part of "Class1".

Comment: Thanks. I'm always try to give "significant" names for vars in my code. Here is such names just because this was "quic example" code. But you are absolutely right.