# In python, how do I call a class multiple times and have randint be random?

Tags: python, class, random

In Python, I was trying to make a character using a class with a random integer as a health value, but the result is the same every time.

```
class Player():
    life = randint(25,30)
    maxhealth = life
    attack = 5
    name = ""
    ......
```

The method I create the players with is like this:

```
playernum = -1
while playernum < 1:
    playernum = int(input("How many players? "))
players = []
for x in range(playernum):
    print("Player " + str(x+1))
    players.append(Player())
```

How do I change it so that the health value is different for each player I create?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using instance attributes:

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.life = randint(25,30)
        self.maxhealth = self.life
        self.attack = 5
        self.name = ""
```

You currently have class attributes which are only evaluated once. Add a print inside your class and you will see `"here"` only appear once:

```
class Player():
    print("here")
    life = randint(25,30)
    maxhealth = life
    attack = 5
    name = ""
```

If you do the same inside the init method you will see the print each time you create an instance:

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        print("here")
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__):

```
class Player():

    def __init__(self):
        self.life = randint(25,30)
        self.maxhealth = life
        self.attack = 5
        self.name = ""
        ......
```

See also [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do).