# What do super(MyObject, self).__init__() do in class MyObject __init__() function?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

```
class MyObject1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyObject1, self).__init__()
        pass

class MyObject2(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(MyObject2, self).__init__()
        pass
```

I have read a python27 code like this,

I know 'super' means father class constructor function,

but I cannot understand why these two classes call themselves' constructor function '`__init__`',

it seems don't have any practical effect.

Comment: Try extending a class that actually does something in the initialization, and it will have an effect

Comment: Are those two actual classes you encountered "in the wild" and you are asking why those are using `super`, or is the question about what `super.init` does in general?

Comment: it seems lots of questions been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/how-to-use-super-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are some pretty basic OO methods in Python. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do).

`super` and `self` are similar:

> super() lets you avoid referring to the base class explicitly, which
> can be nice. But the main advantage comes with multiple inheritance,
> where all sorts of fun stuff can happen. See the standard docs on
> super if you haven't already.

(from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods))

Here's an example of `super` in action:

```
class Animal(object):
     def __init__(self, speed, is_mammal):
          self.speed = speed
          self.is_mammal = is_mammal

class Cat(Animal):
     def __init__(self, is_hungry):
          super().__init__(10, True)
          self.is_hungry = is_hungry

barry = Cat(True)
print(f"speed: {barry.speed}")
print(f"is a mammal: {barry.is_mammal}")
print(f"feed the cat?: {barry.is_hungry}")
```

You can see that `super` is calling the base class (the class that the current class inherits), followed by an access modifier, accessing the base class' `.__init__()` method. It's like `self`, but for the base class.