# Super in this case makes no sense to me

Tags: python-3.x

```
class SimpleRoundedCorners(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleRoundedCorners, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
```

This makes no sense to me. I've read how super() works, and maybe I'm just not good enough at objects to grasp it. This seems like a very redundant call. Why am I calling init twice on the same object?

Comment: If you translate this code to English, it says something like *"a `SimpleRoundedCorners` is a kind of `QWidget`, and to initialise one you need to do the same things required to initialise a `QWidget` and also call its `initUI` method."* There is no `__init__` method here that gets called twice; there are two `__init__` methods and one calls the other.

Comment: @kaya3 Nice one!

Comment: @kaya3 That was a great explanation as well. I wasn't thinking about it that way!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'super' do in Python? - difference between super().\_\_init\_\_() and explicit superclass \_\_init\_\_()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python-difference-between-super-init-and-expl)

Answer (score 1):

In OOP, `super()` is very useful for the purpose of **multiple-inheritance**. It gives you access to methods and attributes from a superclass, to be used in a sub/child class, which saves a lot of time and effort.

The second `init` call is used to access the superclass from the base/sub class. Where you pass in the arguments required by the superclass's `init` constructor; such that when you instantiate the base/sub class, you only pass in the arguments required by **its** `init` constructor only, not the arguments required for the superclass's `init` constructor. A nice example of that is looking at the implementation in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38586279/what-do-supermyobject-self-init-do-in-class-myobject-init-functio/38586551#38586551).

Moreover, you can just write `super().__init__()` without explicitly referring to the base class.

Comment: Thank you. After re-reading the super() definition with your explanation and link it makes total sense.