# self refers to the newly created object; in other class methods, it refers to the instance whose method was called.?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am learning OOP in python and following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python) stackoverflow answers and [this post](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/)

In the blog post writer explained this :

> In the **init** method, self refers to the newly created object; in
> other class methods, it refers to the instance whose method was
> called.

I understood first part of this line , but couldn't understand second part of this line

> "in other class methods, it refers to the instance whose method was
> called."

What is the meaning of second line ? can someone please explain with explample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you make a class:

```
class Rectangle():
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def volume(self):
        return self.height * self.width
```

What they're saying isn't much really, it just sounds confusing.

**Let's say we make a new Rectangle:**

`rect = Rectangle(5, 4)`

In this case, `self` is referring to the newly created Rectangle `rect`.

If we call the `volume` method of `rect`...

`print rect.volume()`

Python will inject the object `rect` as the `self` variable, and use `rect`s height and width. Since we called the `volume` method of `rect`, `self` refers to `rect`.

*It might help to think of calling `rect.volume()` in these terms: `Rectangle.volume(rect)`.*

I believe the author was trying to explain the mechanism of `self`, but possibly made it a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The text you're quoting is, at best, confusing and misleading. But here is an example.

```
class A(object):
    def p(self):
       print(self)

 a1 = A()        # create two instances
 a2 = A()
 a1.p()          # calls A.p(a1); self is a1
 a2.p()          # calls A.p(a2); self is a2
```

What the second sentence means is that `self` is a reference to the object you are calling the method on: the object before the `.`. `a1.p()` is the same as `A.p(a1)` and the method is passed `a1` for `self`.

The reason I said what you quoted is misleading is that it implies that `__init__()` is different from other methods. It's not. `__init__()` is a method like any other. It is automatically passed the instance it is to operate on as its first argument. It's just that it doesn't yet have a name when `__init__()` is called, because it's not given a name until it has been initialized. But `self` is still the instance.

The one that's really different is `__new__()`, but you will probably not need it for a while, if ever.