# When to use and when not to use __init__ in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, oop

I just started learning Python from Learn Python The Hard Way by Zed A. Shaw.
However,  I am confused about when should one use the init method?
Is it mandatory to use it? 
What happens of I don't?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python \_\_init\_\_ and self what do they do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps someone else has a better answer, but this is how I understand it.  The metaphor of a blueprint for building a house works well here. Say you have a housing development with many different houses that look essentially the same with slight variations. Building a house requires that you do essentially the same thing each time, then adding customizations.

Your class declarations are like blueprints, telling your Python program everything it needs to know about a house. However, your `__init__` method provides the instructions for the absolute basic requirements for that object.

Just like you can't have a house without a door, you can't have a `Student` object or a `Pet` object without a few basic properties like name, age. Your `__init__` method will tell Python what it needs to do whenever you create a new Student or Pet, just like a blueprint will tell a general contractor that every house needs a door.

The `__init__` method also establishes the object's `self` variable. `self` allows you to be specific about variable assignment for a *single copy* of a class.

Hope this helps!