# Init in classes - is the first argument a stand in for the instance?

Tags: python

I have been trying to fully understand this for a while now, and practically speaking I think I understand what happens but I can't seem to find anywhere that confirms wether I understood it correctly:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, this):
        self.something = this
example = test("writing")
```

My question is: In the above example, is it correct that self is simply a stand-in for the instance I am creating? Meaning that when i create an instance and assign it to "example", then "example is put in place of self and behind the scenes does something resembling this:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(example, this):
        example.something = this
example = test("writing")
```

Furthermore, does that also mean that as long as I am still working with this on a class basis (say in tandem with another class) I should still be using self.something, while I should be using example.something if I am working with it on an instance level?

I hope that made somewhat sense, im still trying to wrap my head properly around all of it, so let me know if I need to try and rephrase it.

For reference sake, should someone else end up asking the same, this reply: [Python __init__ and self what do they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do) almost did the trick for me, and only really left me a bit in doubt about the above questions.

Comment: `self` is the object you are initialising, but it's not "standing in" for `example`. `example` doesn't get assigned to until _after_ the initialisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct. `self` is the instance of the class (i.e. the object) and you use it inside the class code (inside it's methods).

While the first argument *can* be named something else (`example` in your second code), the convention is that we always use `self` or the code might be highly confusing for other programmers. But you got the gist right by doing that, the `example` variable in the class (i.e. the `self` in your first code) and the `example` variable outside of the class is basically the same thing.

By the way, I'd also avoid the following two things:

- having a class name that starts with a small leter case,
- using a variable name `this` (since a variable named `this` does in some other languages essentially what `self` does in Python).

Comment: Thank you, and good to know in regards to using "this", would be quite the annoying habbit to have to struggle loosing it later on.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, variables do not "contain" objects, they refer to them.  So:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, this):
        self.something = this

example = test("writing")
```

In this case `example` is a reference to the new object, but so is `self`.  It is perfectly legal, and common, to have multiple references to the same object.

If you did:

```
another = example
```

this would *not* create a new object but have another reference to the same object.  `another`, `example` (and `self`) would be references to the same single object.

You can test this by looking at the object's unique identifier, using `id()`.  Add:

```
another = example

print id(another)
print id(example)
```

you will find that their id's are the same.

Comment: Neat, gonna mess around with id() a bit.

Comment: @BlueNebulae:  in the C implementation of Python the number is actually a virtual address (C pointer value) and demonstrates the principle quite well.