# What happens when we give a function definition in a class in Python

Tags: python, function, class

I'm learning python on my own out of interest, but I face a lot of questions when I get into "class".

In this post: 
[What happens when you initialise instance variables outside of __init__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486395/what-happens-when-you-initialise-instance-variables-outside-of-init?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa&newreg=a3be2a9fcd7e42a69a2445c07104e576)

The answer by Dietrich Epp gave out a detailed explanation of what really happens in a class.
Dietrich said that the three cases in the editor are the same.

However, when I type the following things in command line:

```
# Set inside __init__
class MyClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
objA = MyClassA()

# Set inside other method
class MyClassB:
    def my_initialize(self):
        self.x = 0
objB = MyClassB()
objB.my_initialize()

# Set from outside any method, no self
class MyClassC:
    pass
objC = MyClassC()
objC.x = 0

print(objA.x)
print(objB.my_initialize())
print(objC.x)
```

It turns out that the middle of the printing result is 'none' which means that instead of giving out 0, objB.my_initialize() return to none.

Can anyone help explain this? 
It seems that the three cases are somehow different to me...

Comment: If you called `objA.__init__()` it *too* would print `None`.. You are printing the return value of a method, **not the attribute the method set**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `objB`, you need to call the function first, then get the value of `x`. So your code goes from

```
print(objB.my_initialize())
```

to

```
objB.my_initialize()
print(objB.x)
```

This is because `objB.my_initialize()` only sets the value of `x`, and doesn't return anything, hence why you are getting `None`.

Comment: For clarity, the default return value of Python functions/methods without an explicit return value is `None`