# Importing a method from a folder in python

Tags: python, python-import

I want to use a Python from a file in another folder.

The method is called `writeToFiles`. It is in a file called `files.py` which is in a folder called `Utils`.

The program that calls this method is in a folder called `ratslam` that also contains the `Utils` folder.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question and show the code that you've written. All you have provided is a statement of intent, which doesn't seem too difficult to achieve. What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: I solved the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming your file structure is:

```
Utils/
    files.py

my_program.py
```

Create an empty file called [**init**.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do) in `Utils` folder and root of the project.

```
Utils/
    __init__.py
    files.py
__init__.py
my_program.py
```

Then you should be able to add this line to the top of `my_program.py`

```
 from Utils.files import writeToFiles
```

Comment: what have I to write in __init__.py?

Comment: thanks it works. I create an empty file called __init__

Answer (score 0):

For importing modules from folder, you need to use:

```
from Utils.files import writeToFiles
```