# Tensorflow session in a class in python?

Tags: python, class, session, tensorflow

I want to use tensorflow gradients for a computation of other quantities later on. I need to numerically compute the objective function and gradients as functions in a class (This class then is used in the remaining suite). However, I am getting error for the below code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        x=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(2))
        func = tf.cos(14.5 * x[0] - 0.3) + (x[1] + 0.2) * x[1] + (x[0] + 0.2) * x[0]
        diff_func = tf.gradients(func,x)

        sess = tf.Session()

    def getFunc(self,coords):
        return self.sess.run(self.func,feed_dict={self.x:coords})

    def getGrad(self,coords):
        grad = self.sess.run(self.diff_func,feed_dict={self.x:coords})
        return grad

MyClass = MyClass()
MyClass.getFunc([0.362,0.556])
MyClass.getGrad([0.362,0.556])
```

The error I am getting is:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 19, in 
    MyClass.getFunc([0.362,0.556])

File "", line 11, in getFunc
    return self.sess.run(self.func,feed_dict={self.x:coords})

AttributeError: MyClass instance has no attribute 'sess'

Not sure how I can get this class running correctly.
Thanks.

Comment: You may define  `sess = tf.Session()` in top outside this class.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, 'self' tells which variables and methods belongs to a class. So you have to tell that (x, func, diff_func and sess) belong to the MyClass. So modify the code as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(2))
        self.func = tf.cos(14.5 * self.x[0] - 0.3) + (self.x[1] + 0.2) * self.x[1] + (self.x[0] + 0.2) * self.x[0]
        self.diff_func = tf.gradients(self.func, self.x)

        self.sess = tf.Session()

    def getFunc(self, coords):
        return self.sess.run(self.func, feed_dict={self.x: coords})

    def getGrad(self, coords):
        grad = self.sess.run(self.diff_func, feed_dict={self.x: coords})
        return grad


MyClass = MyClass()
MyClass.getFunc([0.362, 0.556])
print(MyClass.getGrad([0.362, 0.556]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `sess = tf.Session()` with `self.sess = tf.Session()`.

Comment: Didn't work. Still the error "Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-3690fea79774>", line 19, in <module>
    MyClass.getFunc([0.362,0.556])

  File "<ipython-input-19-3690fea79774>", line 11, in getFunc
    return self.sess.run(self.func,feed_dict={self.x:coords})

AttributeError: MyClass instance has no attribute 'func'"

Comment: This problem is solved a similar way. You must write `self.func` if you want `func` to be accessible anywhere in the class. In the snippet you've posted, the variables defined in `__init__` are only accessible from within `__init__`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/625097/4030272) elaborates on how it works.

On a broader note, learning Python and TensorFlow by themselves is a challenge. Learning them at the same time is a recipe for frustration. You can save yourself some hassle by getting the fundamentals of Python down before moving on to TensorFlow.

Happy hacking!

Comment: I have a very specific question. I have carved out a minimal code where the problem can be reproduced. Wouldn't it be more efficient to provide the corrected full working code? Then, I can build on it for more complicated cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a variable inside constructor viz `__init__`. Then you need to associate `self` for showing that this variable belongs to that particular class. 
In this case, `__init__` is the constructor of `MyClass`, then for defining `sess`, you need to associate `self` before it such as `self.var_name`. So that class functions `getFunc()` and `getGrad()` can understand that `sess` variable is an object variable and can use it.
So just replace `self` with `self.sess` in the constructor.