# Scrapy: NameError: name 'url' is not defined

Tags: python, scrapy

when I set start_urls inside a Scrapy spider class, the fllowing code is OK:

```
class InfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'info'
    allowed_domains = ['isbn.szmesoft.com']
    isbns = list(set(pd.read_csv('E:/books.csv')['ISBN']))
    url = 'http://isbn.szmesoft.com/isbn/query?isbn='
    start_urls = [url + isbns[0]]
```

But then I got the error  `Scrapy: NameError: name 'url' is not defined` when I rewrite my code as follows:

```
class InfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'info'
    allowed_domains = ['isbn.szmesoft.com']
    isbns = list(set(pd.read_csv('E:/books.csv')['ISBN']))
    url = 'http://isbn.szmesoft.com/isbn/query?isbn='
    start_urls = [url + isbn for isbn in isbns[:3]]
```

Maybe I can solve this problem in other ways，but I want to know the reason for the ERROR

Answer (score 2):

There are only four ranges in Python: `LEGB`, because the local scope of the `class` definition and the local extent of the `list derivation` are not nested functions, so they do not form the Enclosing scope.

Therefore, they are two separate local scopes that cannot be accessed from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `__init__`:

```
class InfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'info'
        self.allowed_domains = ['isbn.szmesoft.com']
        self.isbns = list(set(pd.read_csv('E:/books.csv')['ISBN']))
        self.url = 'http://isbn.szmesoft.com/isbn/query?isbn='
        self.start_urls = [url + isbn for isbn in isbns[:3]]
```

Then when you call it do `self.` before it

Comment: Is it a bug of scrapy ? cause my two pieces of code above are so similar

Comment: @MJ_0826 It's not a bug of scrapy, scrapy is not causing this, it's class

Comment: @MJ_0826 What do you mean?

Comment: the first code 'url' is defined but the second is not, the only difference is the last line

Comment: @MJ_0826 Edited my answer

Comment: @MJ_0826 The error is NameError so that's why need an `__init__`

Comment: @MJ_0826 See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do

Comment: @U9-Forward I think last line won't be coming in __init__ and should be in separate function

Comment: @UpasanaMittal Yeah that's another option, but in the OP's example he wanted it all as a class variables

Comment: I know the reason, it's because of 'for', you can see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass string of it and try printing url so that you can also go and check it on browser if ut actually exists or not.

```
start_urls = [url + str(isbn) for isbn in isbns[:3]]
print(start_urls)
```

Comment: @MJ_0826 But the only change you have done is in `line 6`

Comment: that's why I am very confused

Comment: @MJ_0826 Can you post stacktrace? I want to see the line is facing error.

Comment: I know the reason, it's because of 'for', you can see my answer below