# The value returns from Class Objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning a Bayesian A/B test course by myself. However in the following code, it has a Class Object within some functions. For the following code:`bandits = [Bandit(p) for p in BANDIT_PROBABILITIES]`.

I know it applies `0.2`,`0.5` and `0.75` to the Bandit Class object, however what the outputs for the statement?  Does it from the function: `def pull(self)` or `def sample(self)` in this Class, since both of them return some values in the Bandit Class. By understanding that, then I can know what the `b` loops though later in this code.

Any reference link or article is also appreciated. thanks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import beta


NUM_TRIALS = 2000
BANDIT_PROBABILITIES=[0.2,0.5,0.75]

class Bandit(object):
  def __init__(self, p): #p=winning
    self.p = p
    self.a = 1
    self.b = 1

  def pull(self):
    return np.random.random() < self.p

  def sample(self):
    return np.random.beta(self.a, self.b)

  def update(self, x):
    self.a =self.a+ x
    self.b =self.b+ 1 - x  #x is 0 or 1


def plot(bandits, trial):
  x = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)
  for b in bandits:
    y = beta.pdf(x, b.a, b.b)
    plt.plot(x, y, label="real p: %.4f" % b.p)
  plt.title("Bandit distributions after %s trials" % trial)
  plt.legend()
  plt.show()


def experiment():
  bandits = [Bandit(p) for p in BANDIT_PROBABILITIES]

  sample_points = [5,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000,1500,1999]
  for i in range(NUM_TRIALS):

    # take a sample from each bandit
    bestb = None
    maxsample = -1
    allsamples = [] # let's collect these just to print for debugging
    for b in bandits:
      sample = b.sample()
      allsamples.append("%.4f" % sample)
      if sample > maxsample:
        maxsample = sample
        bestb = b
    if i in sample_points:
      print("current samples: %s" % allsamples)
      plot(bandits, i)

    # pull the arm for the bandit with the largest sample
    x = bestb.pull()

    # update the distribution for the bandit whose arm we just pulled
    bestb.update(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  experiment()
```

Comment: "however what the outputs for the statement? " I'm not sure I understand your question, but that is a list-comprehension. Have you tried checking for yourself? It's going to be a list of `Bandit` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
bandits = [Bandit(p) for p in BANDIT_PROBABILITIES]
```

is called list comprehension and it's basically a way to create a list. For example you can see [this](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) for a reference (there a lot of sources).

The basic idea is that uses a mechanism like:

```
[ expression for item in list if conditional ]
```

So, in your case `BANDIT_PROBABILITIES` is the list above containing 3 elements and the expression your list comprehension evaluates it's just instances of your `Bandit` class. In other words you will end up with a list containing 3 instances of your `Bandit` class each initialized with a different argument.

The `pull(self)` or `sample(self)` are just function belonging to the class and they are not used in this statement. They could be used if you had a call from your `__init__(self, p)` member function.

To make it simple, when you create a class instance only the `__init__` is used. If inside the latter function are other calls to member functions like `sample()` etc then they are called also but the output in your list comprehension would be still a list with 3 `Bandit` instances.

Maybe you should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do) (and any other since there are plenty of sources) about `__init__` functionality.

Comment: So, when we first call bandits = [Bandit(p) for p in BANDIT_PROBABILITIES], in fact only def __init__(self, p) is running, the rest of the function won't run until i call   them later, like b.sample.

Answer (score 1):

It return 3 object of Bandit class with initialisation with the different p probability.

Furthur down the line, sample = b.sample(), it will return the result of np.random.beta(self.a, self.b)

Answer (score 1):

`bandits = [Bandit(p) for p in BANDIT_PROBABILITIES]` is a list comprehension. `BANDIT_PROBABILITIES` is a list of 3 float values so `bandits` is a list containing 3 objects of `Bandit` class created with 3 different values of `p` attribute:

```
print(type(bandit[0]))
print(bandits[0].p)
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.Bandit'>
0.2
```

Only method `__init__()` was called so far to initiate objects. Every bandit in the list `bandits` has attributes `p, a, b` and methods `pull(), sample(), update()`.