# Print class instance variable from another class method

Tags: python, class-method

I have a class which initialises a person, then another class to handle the manipulation and displaying of that persons details. When I try to use the display_person method it prints the class instance rather than the fullname. I tried adding dunder methods `__str__` and `__repr__` however that doesn't resolve it.

```
import itertools

class Person:

    num_of_emps = 0
    id_iter = itertools.count(1)

    def __init__(self, firstname: str, surname: str, address: str, email: str):
        self.firstname = str(firstname)
        self.surname = str(surname)
        self.fullname = str(firstname) + ' ' + str(surname)
        self.email = str(email)
        self.address = str(address)

        person_id = next(self.id_iter)
        self.person_id = int(person_id)
        Person.num_of_emps += 1


class PersonActions:
    def display_person(self, fullname) -> None:
        print(f'This is {fullname.__str__()}.')

p1 = Person('Lucas', 'S', '100 st', 'lucasshaw@email.com')
p2 = Person('Rosie', 'B', '101 st', 'rosiebryan@email.com')
action = PersonActions()
print(action.display_person(p1))
```

The output is:

```
This is <__main__.Person object at 0x10aeebe20>.
None.
```

Would the architecture be better if I added the display_person method to the Person class directly? From research I have seen that its better to keep these methods separate for cohesion purposes as per [this](https://bond-kirill-alexandrovich.medium.com/best-python-program-architecture-79f29cad127b). How can I get the display_person method to print the full name? I plan to do the same with other details later on.

Why does it print 'None' also?

I have looked at [class employee print method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619007/class-employee-print-method) but still can't figure it out.

Comment: It prints `None` also because in addition to printing within `display_person` you *also* print the return value of that function.  "I have a class which initialises a person, then another class to handle the manipulation and displaying of that persons details."  this is a bizarre separation of duties, fwiw.

Comment: Please show your `__str__()` method, that should have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass in an instance of `Person`, so you should handle it as such in your other class:

```py
class PersonActions:
    def display_person(self, person) -> None:
        print(f'This is {person.fullname.__str__()}.')
```

Actually you don't need the `.__str()__`, nor do you need the `print()` when you are calling this method:

```py
class PersonActions:
    def display_person(self, person) -> None:
        print(f'This is {person.fullname}.')

p1 = Person('Lucas', 'S', '100 st', 'lucasshaw@email.com')
p2 = Person('Rosie', 'B', '101 st', 'rosiebryan@email.com')
action = PersonActions()
action.display_person(p1)
```

**Update:**

or you meant to include a `__str__()` method like this:

```py
class Person:
    ...   # Current implementation elided - see code from OP
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname

class PersonActions:
    def display_person(self, person) -> None:
        print(f'This is {person}.')
```

The `f-string` formatting will automatically call the `__str__()` method for you.

Comment: I think he wants printing a `Person` to automatically show the `fullname`, using a `__str__()` method.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know f-string called the __str__. To clarify, I plan to include more methods to show the other details of the Person (ie, id, email, address) so `{person.fullname}` is ideal

Comment: @Barmar yes I might end up just printing all Person details within a single function so that is also an option

Answer (score 1):

Defining the `__str__()` method should work:

```
class Person:

    num_of_emps = 0
    id_iter = itertools.count(1)

    def __init__(self, firstname: str, surname: str, address: str, email: str):
        self.firstname = str(firstname)
        self.surname = str(surname)
        self.fullname = str(firstname) + ' ' + str(surname)
        self.email = str(email)
        self.address = str(address)

        person_id = next(self.id_iter)
        self.person_id = int(person_id)
        Person.num_of_emps += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname

class PersonActions:
    def display_person(self, person: Person) -> None:
        print(f'This is {person}.')
```

You don't need to call `.__str__()` explicitly. The f-string converts the values to strings automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your class:

```
  def __str__(self):
        return(f"{self.fullname}")
```

and then `print(p1)`