# Different memory address for same object

Tags: python, class, oop, object

Why am I getting two different memory addresses for the same object?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPY7p.png]

Comment: Nope it should give you error. Restart your spyder or whatever that ide is.

Comment: This code alone should raise a NameError.

Comment: Do you already have a variable `x` in your namespace (i.e. in one of the first 56 runs you did)? It might be using that is why

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy how to overcome this?

Comment: Also please dont put image of your code. Others have to type whole thing to debug. Always paste code as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- your `x` inside class `__init__` should give error. Your code is running because you are using IDE like syder/jupyter which store previously run code's result. If you restart your IDE and run same code again it will raise error `name 'x' is not defined`
- If you want to reference `x` (object of class) use self to get that reference.

```
>>> class test:
...     def __init__(self, max):
...         print(self, "b")
...
>>> x = test(2)
<__main__.test object at 0x0000016A080052C8> b
>>> print(x,"a")
<__main__.test object at 0x0000016A080052C8> a
```

- as you can see both `x` and `self` inside `__init__` have same address.
- Some reference to look at : [What __init__ and self do on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/what-init-and-self-do-on-python)