# Method within Class not activating

Tags: python, class, methods

Here is my code, my issue is as the title above states, the input text does not appear and neither does the print below. I am new to Python so sorry for a simple mistake

```
class Horse:
    colour = ''
    height = ''
    speed = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = input("Enter an integer: ")

        if(self.speed != 0):
            self.gallop = (3 * self.speed)

        print(self.gallop)
```

Comment: Where do you create `Horse` instance?

Comment: The input and print values within the method are not being activated and I am unsure as to why

Comment: Cannot reproduce - except the `input` statement should be wrapped with `int()`

Comment: What would I use the Horse instance for? Would it not suffice that there is a class? I just want to pass these class variables to the method

Comment: Have a read of [What __init__ and self do on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/what-init-and-self-do-on-python) `self` represents an instance of `Horse`, and `__init__` is its constructor. If you don't create an instance, it will never be executed.

Comment: Let me give you a constructive criticism. As a developer you'll always face problems you don't no how to solve. StackOverflow helps a lot with some issues, because there's a huge probability that you're not the first to deal with the problem, but the documentation of the language, framework or whatever you're using helps a lot either and should be your first method to solve problems. Always read the documentation, it's not there without a purpose. [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an instance of the class... because so your code in the constructor is invoked

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Horse()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make an instance of your object by initiating it. Here is the full program:

```py
class Horse:
    colour = ''
    height = ''
    speed = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = input("Enter an integer: ")

        if(self.speed != 0):
            self.gallop = (3 * self.speed)

        print(self.gallop)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Horse()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but if I try to make an instance of the class at the top of the class before the method, it gives me an error. The error says the type is not defined. The actual class variable is not defined.

Comment: You can't initiate something before it's declaration in procedural programming. Remember: Python supports multi paradigm programming. To avoid C like procedural execution, always put the code you want to execute into the `"if __name__ == '__main__':"` scope, as this is the OOP approach of execution.

With the `"if __name__ == '__main__':"` usage, you can program in the typical C#/Java/Rust/Go way. Without the `"if __name__ == '__main__':"` it would execute your code in the typical C-like style (procedural town down execution).

Answer (score 1):

You did not create an horse instance. Add the code below.

```py
def create_horse():
    new_horse = Horse() # this will ask for an integer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_horse()
```