# How to get a variable value from a method to use in another method (of the same class) in Python

Tags: python, class, oop

The sample code is below.
I am trying to get the inputted value for the 'name' variable from the first method and use it to print a message using the second method (method2).
I would appreciate any advice on how to do this or alternative ways to go about it.

```
  class User:

     method1(self):
        name = input("Enter name")

     method2(self):
        greeting = print("Hello", name)
```

Comment: Have you read any tutorials on OOP? They should all explain the concept of object attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [What __init__ and self do on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/what-init-and-self-do-on-python)

You should assign the input string to class variable

```py
 method1(self):
        self.name = input("Enter name")
```

and then you can use it in other method.

```py
method2(self):
        greeting = print("Hello", self.name)
```

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

#

class User():

```
def method1(self): 
    self.name = input('Enter your name:')

def method2(self): 
    print("Name is", self.name )
```

obj = User()

obj.method1()

obj.method2()

#

Also read this

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/