# What do __intit__ ,__name__ and __main__ do?

Tags: python

I have seen programs with the dunder method's `__init__`/`__main__`. I have no idea what they do, can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm almost sure that you did not search this question before asking.

Comment: Did you remember to [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) before posting? [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/what-init-and-self-do-in-python/625097) & [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)  Since you haven't done this, you are not ready to post a question.

Answer (score 0):

#### `__init__`:

The init method is similar to a constructor in other languages. It initializes your class. Example:

```py
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
     self.bar = "Foobar"
```

As you can see, I am initializing a new class `Foo`, saying that `Foo` has a field called `bar` within the `__init__` method.

#### `__main__`:

`__main__` is the name of the scope in which the top level executes. This is why you commonly see this in Python code:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This means that the `__name__` returns to say that yes, we are running this as a script (example: `python3 main.py`).