# Why am I not able to open google.com using Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

This project I'm working on is the same project I was working on when I asked this StackOverflow question:
[I'm getting a name error when running Selenium-based code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67071958/im-getting-a-name-error-when-running-selenium-based-code).
Again, both the questions are related to Selenium.
However, this time I am not getting any errors but the website I want to be opened isn't opening.
And I'm sure my chrome_directory is right. Idk why Google.com isn't opening.
This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
  class Infow():

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Chrome Driver@C drive\ChromeDriverExtracted\chromedriver_win32 (2)\chromedriver.exe')
    def get_infow(self, query):
        self.query = query
        self.driver.get(url="https://www.google.com/")
        assist.Infow()
        assist.get_infow("exe")
```

This is the text I see in the terminal

```
      "D:\Rocland\Selenium Pycharm\Scripts\python.exe" "D:/PycharmProjects/Selenium 
      Pycharm/Selenium for trevor.py"
      Process finished with exit code 0
```

My apologies if this question is senseless. I'm a Selenium beginner
and all the Stack *I* saw don't answer my problem.
(I'm not sure if this will help but I'm using PyCharm on Win10)
I hope I made my points clear and anyone's help will be gladly accepted.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have indentation problem in the second row: `class Infow()`
Try this and then debug by yourself.

```
from selenium import webdriver


def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='your path')
    self.driver.get(url="https://www.google.com/")
```

Class should look like this:

```
class Testing:
    def __init__(self, name=None, number=None):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
```

Check the example based on your case. I use Linux, so my `executable_path` differs from your. Yours seems to be correct because you do not have any errors:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
assert "Google" in driver.title
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gLFyf.gsfi")))
input_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".gLFyf.gsfi")
input_field.send_keys("Why are people so mad?")
input_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".yuRUbf")))
results = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".yuRUbf>a>h3")
for result in results:
    print(result.text)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Furthermore, I've implemented in with **unittest**. This should answer all your questions:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import unittest


class SiteTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')

    def test(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get('https://google.com/')
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
        assert "Google" in driver.title
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gLFyf.gsfi")))
        input_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".gLFyf.gsfi")
        input_field.send_keys("Why are people so mad?")
        input_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".yuRUbf")))
        results = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".yuRUbf>a>h3")
        for result in results:
            print(result.text)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same output @vitaliis. What should I do?

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645129/pycharm-exit-code-0#:~:text=Saying%20that%20the%20Process%20finished,which%20is%20useful%20debug%20information. In short, exit code 0 is not an error. You are not aking any output in your program.

Comment: Also, check my answer here. It should help you a lot. Try running this small program and improve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67148905/python-web-scraping-for-walmart/67161826#67161826

Comment: So to conclude is my Chrome Driver file location the cause of Selenium not being able to open Google?

Comment: I'll try to put wrong location  and will check what is the error on my side

Comment: Ok I'll wait here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231324/discussion-between-vitaliis-and-philip).

Comment: Check the example