# TypeError: open_ssh_tunnel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, init, self

> So i know this question has been asked many times but i cant seem to
> understand what i need to
> put in the **init** def. When i am calling the open_ssh_tunnel function. The error
> TypeError: open_ssh_tunnel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.
> Any help would be much appreciated.

```
def __init__(self):
    ???

def open_ssh_tunnel(self, verbose=False):
    """Open an SSH tunnel and connect using a username and password.
    :param verbose: Set to True to show logging
    :return tunnel: Global SSH tunnel connection
    """
    if verbose:
        sshtunnel.DEFAULT_LOGLEVEL = logging.DEBUG

    global tunnel
    tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (self.ssh_host, 22),
        ssh_username= self.ssh_username,
        ssh_password= self.ssh_password,
        remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)
    )
    tunnel.start()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What \_\_init\_\_ and self do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/what-init-and-self-do-in-python)

Comment: I suggest you explore basic oop before trying to learn 'chunks' of knowledge that will make your work even harder.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code in `open_ssh_tunnel`, it looks like you are using 3 instance variables `ssh_host`, `ssh_username` and `ssh_password`. These instance variables should be defined in your `__init__` method since you are calling them using `self`. Something like:

```
class SSHExample:
  def __init__(self):
    self.ssh_host = "<insert ssh host value>"
    self.ssh_username = "<insert username value>"
    self.ssh_password = "<insert password value>"
```

More likely, you will have to pass in these 3 values when you initialize the object, since the host, username, and password will not always be the same values. So the `__init__` method would look like:

```
def __init__(self, host, username, password):
  self.ssh_host = host
  self.ssh_username = username
  self.ssh_password = password
```

These three instance variables would then be used in the  `open_ssh_tunnel` method you have defined.

`self` is an instance variable itself that refers to the object that you have initialized. You would only use this to call the object's other instance variables within the other methods in the class. An example of initializing this with the second `__init__` above would look like:

```
ssh_obj = SSHExample('fake_host', 'fake_user', 'fake_pass')
print(ssh_obj.ssh_host) # prints "fake_host"
print(ssh_obj.ssh_username) # prints "fake_user"
```

Comment: Thank you so much that helped me a lot + i finally understood the __init__ function. Thank you so much this was driving me nuts ;))

Comment: Glad to hear it :)