# Class inside Class: Error: Page1.__init__.My_Data.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Name'

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

When i try to start my script, i get a error. I have main class `Page1` and inside is `My_Data` class and `function1` function. The error is:

```
TypeError: Page1.__init__.<locals>.My_Data.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Name'
```

MyCode.py:

```
class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, other, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        self.configure(bg='white')

        class My_Data():
            def __init__(self):
                self.Name: str
                self.Year: float
                

        def function1(self):

            My_Dictionary = {}
            x = cursor.execute("sql")
```

Comment: The `def __init__(self):` in the `class My_Data():` block is missing the `Name` and `Year` argument definition (only `self` is required). Please [reference this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/625097/) for what you might be trying to do.

Comment: @metatoaster I'm sorry I did not understand. How can I fix?

Comment: You should start with a [basic tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) on how to create classes, with `__init__` that accept some arguments, and get back the attribute from it.  Also you need to assign the arguments to `self.Name` and `self.Year`, the type annotation doesn't do any assignments.

Comment: There's rarely a good reason to nest classes in Python. A few frameworks use nested classes for special purposes, but in most code it just is more confusing than writing your classes at the top level of the module. The Python language itself doesn't consider a nested class to have any special meaning (it doesn't get special access to the surrounding class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `My_Data` class doesn't have parameters Name and Year in its `__init__` function. Just add the two params.

```py
class My_Data():
    def __init__(self, Name, Year):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Year = Year
```

Comment: Instead here I have to use ".self" for Name and Year? Data = My_data (Name = row [1], Year = Row [2])

Comment: The `__init__` function won't recognize `Name` and `Year` keywords since you didn't provide the arguments in the definition of the function. Having `self.Name` doesn't assume the value will be passed via argument in the initiator.

Comment: So I have to use Data = My_data (self.Name = row[1], self.Year = Row[2]) ? Or do I write Data = My_data (Name = row [1], Year = Row [2])? Thank you

Comment: Keep `Data=My_Data(Name=row[1], Year=row[2])`, and change the `__init__` function to what I defined in my comment.